# Unable to set up Ballerina slalpha2 as SDK in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, ballerina

I have recently reinstalled Ballerina on MacOS Catalina. My current distribution is set to slalpha2. The distribution is located in the standard place, `/Library/Ballerina/distributions/ballerina-slalpha2`.

I'm trying to set this up as an SDK in IntelliJ, where I'm using the Ballerina plugin, but when selecting that directory, I get the message "The selected directory is not a valid home for Ballerina SDK". I've tried a few of its subdirectories but those didn't work either. What should I be pointing it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that the Ballerina IntelliJ plugin development is currently on hold and therefore the Swan Lake support is yet to be added.
You can still use the intellij plugin for Ballerina 1.x versions but I'm afraid your only option would be using the vscode plugin for the moment, if you are using Ballerina Swan Lake versions.